# MYSQL Find data in one table based on one of two fields in another table

Tags: mysql

Complete noob question, so apologies for that.

I have two tables, a members table with an email address and telephone number in it and a second table that will have email addresses and telephone numbers in it with many instances of the members' telephone number or email address.  I want to query the second table and list all results corresponding to each member's email address or telephone number.

Thanks very much

Comment: The second table has three fields a rowid field an email field and a telephone number field.  Each row may have data in both the email and telephone or in just one of them.  The member is not referenced in the second table.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough query based on the info you supplied:

```
select members_table.*, joined_tables.* 
from members_table, 
((select * from second_table 
 join members_table 
    on members_table.email_address = second_table.email_address)
union /* or intersect if you don't want dupes */
(select * from second_table 
 join members_table 
    on members_table.telephone_number = second_table.telephone_number)
) joined_tables;
```

At least it should give you an idea on how to go about it.